# how to solve cannot find symbol public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult arg0)

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, google-play-services, exoplayer

i have recently updated my google play service library , older version was
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`

and i found that i can not diretly implement that library i have to include whatever i needed one by one so i added

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
```

but after that i am getting like this ,

```
error: package com.google.android.gms.plus.People does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.plus.People.LoadPeopleResult;

error: cannot find symbol
        implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<LoadPeopleResult> {
                                                                                   ^
  symbol: class LoadPeopleResult

error: cannot find symbol
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult arg0) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class LoadPeopleResult
  location: class LoginActivity
```

i have also added `ExoPlayer` library which makes some trouble so i had to update this library and i also have updated firebase library .

does any body have idea how to solve this ? thank you in advance